# (Linux/General) concering /bin/rocks

Tags: sudo, ln

So I am trying to install a software not "supported" by my linux distro (Ubuntu)

I have it under control, but I am curious about some coding I was told to use.

```
 sudo ln -s /bin/true /bin/rocks
 sudo ./setup.sh
```

This was suggested after I received this error:

```
Error: Could not execute command: type rocks 2>&1
```

Question: What does the rocks directory do?

Question Part 2: Can someone explain to me the link I made using 'ln -s?'

I looked at the --help... but I think hearing it a different way would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a funny thing to do, but basically is just making a [soft link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln) to the `true` command. In other words it is making it so the `rocks` command always returns successfully. The problem is that if `rocks` is important to your install, then this is will just make things harder to actually get working.

Comment: Hmm, well I am really new to the true workings in a computer. So can I undo what I have done at a later date if this does become a problem?     This is the other fix I was given, if interested look at WaltL's post a few comments down http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=8944

Comment: To undo, just `sudo rm /bin/rocks`. That will delete the link.

Comment: oh, I just figured there was something more than a physical directory being made in this command. To try an answer the question, is this bin/rocks folder not a universal name? Was this folder just created for the installation of my program? If so I think I understand what is going on.

Comment: I think "/bin/rocks" is a screen saver or something. I'm not sure why your installer would need that.